# Why is remote desktop still not working?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

I regularly use remote desktop to connect to PC's at work instead of going an physically sitting on the machine. We have 2 new computers, 1. Windows 7 2. Windows 8.1 ... I'm trying to connect to them view their internal IP address and it's not having any of it.

On the computers in question I have:

1. Enabled Remote Desktop in Computer Properties.
2. Allowed the port through the Firewall.
3. Allowed Remote Desktop through the firewall.
4. Fixed the IP address so it doesn't change.
5. Stopped the computer sleeping.
6. Enabled Network sharing and visibility options.

I'm running out of ideas and I need to get this up and running before we apply the external ip addresses.

As I mentioned I can remote to other PC's in the office, so it shouldn't be anything wrong with the network.

Comment: If you try and ping the computers, do you get a response? When you say enabled, did you also give permissions to your user to rdp in? What is the actual error message that you're getting (besides the machine wanting none of your rdping)

Comment: how about defining "It's not having any of it"? I'm not aware of that being a recognised error message anywhere in Windows in general, let alone the client or server side of the RDP stack in particular.

Comment: `and it's not having any of it` What does this mean??? What error-message are you getting. Does the machine you're trying to control have a password for the account you're using to get in?

Comment: @Reaces when I ping the IP Addresss I get a response and the time is 5ms and TTL: 128 ... The error message is the general one where it says check the network, computer is turned on and remote desktop is enabled.

Comment: @Rik I get the general error message where it ask's you to check the computer is on and that remote desktop is enabled.

Comment: What checkbox did you tick when enabling RDP? `Allow... with any version or RDP` or the more secure `Only allow with NLA`? What version of Windows do you have on your own PC?

Comment: @Rik I have tried connecting from Windows 7 & 8, the options that have been ticket are that available; Allow remote connections to this computer this is the only tick box available on the machine, it's running Windows 7 Home Premium.

I do have additional options on my computer which is running Windows 7 Proffesional, for example the option you mentioned.

But that tick box option isn't available on the computer I'm attempting to connect with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Windows 7 Home Premium. That version doesn't allow access via Remote Desktop. The ticked option you mention is for "**Remote Assistance**". You need to "**invite**" the remote party to view your computer with "Remote Assistance". You can see this from the checkbox is in the "Remote Assitance" groupbox and not in the "Remote Desktop" groupbox.

If you want to use RDP onto this machine you'll need to upgrade to Professional or use another form of remote control.

[image]